# Mitre Box For Cutting 145mm Skirting

Tags: skirting

do they just not make mitre boxes for  wider skirting? I have some 145mm tall skirting I need to cut and the tallest mitre box I can find is 120mm.

Comment: So make one. Or make a guide so the skirting lays flat.

Comment: What kind of miter box? Is it a literal box that guides a hand saw? Is it a power miter box (usually called a miter saw, but of course, the hand saw designed to be used in a miter box is also called a miter saw). You could, of course, simply mark a straight line on the skirting then cut the line - there's no need to use a miter box (of any sort). It may take a bit of practice, but it _can_ be done... How about a bit more detail, and maybe a picture of your setup?